# How to Use Dialog variable created in another JS file in Current JS file in dojo tool kit

Tags: dojo

I have created Dialog in AddButtonEntryPoint.js file and I want to access that variable in Form.js file to hide the dialog after click on Submit button So, How can i call.

Here is the code which i have written

**AddButtonEntryPoint.js**

```
       var w = new Form({});

        var d = new Dialog({
            id: 'FormDialog',
            title: "Bridge Form",
            style: "width: 270px; height: 270px;",
            content: w,
            onHide: function() {
                // To prevent destroying the dialog before the animation ends
                setTimeout(lang.hitch(this, 'destroyRecursive'), 0);
            }
        });
            d.show();
        };
```

**Form.js**

```
return declare( "mypackage.MyForm", Form, {
    repotextbox: new TextBox({
        name: "text",
        placeHolder: "Enter text here."
    } , dojo.doc.createElement('input')),

    DFMtextbox: new TextBox({
        name: "text",
        placeHolder: "Enter text here."
    } , dojo.doc.createElement('input')),

    submitButton: new Button({
        type: "submit",
        label: "Submit"
    }),

    constructor: function(args) {
        declare.safeMixin(this, args);
    },

    onSubmit: function() { 
        var repositoryID = this.repotextbox.get('value');
        xhr("https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={repositoryID}",{ 
            // The URL of the request 
           method: "GET", 
            handleAs: "json", 
           }).then(
              function(data){ 

                alert(data.success + " " + JSON.stringify(data)); 
              }, 
              function(err){ 
              alert( "Your message could not be sent, please try again."); 
              });
    },    
});
```

}
);

In form.js file, Under onSubmit function I have to hide the dialog created in AddButtonEntryPoint.js when the user click on Submit button.

Answer (score 0):

In Form.js you have to add a property that will reference the Dialog instance

```
return declare( "mypackage.MyForm", Form, {
    myDialog: null, 
    // etc
}
```

Then in AddButtonEntryPoint you can either set this property when you initialize w if you put it after:

```
        var d = new Dialog({
            id: 'FormDialog',
            title: "Bridge Form",
            style: "width: 270px; height: 270px;",
            content: w,
            onHide: function() {
                // To prevent destroying the dialog before the animation ends
                setTimeout(lang.hitch(this, 'destroyRecursive'), 0);
            }
        });

        var w = new Form({
            myDialog: d
        });
```

or you can keep it as it is and call `w.set("myDialog", d);` later - but in this case any code in postCreate that requires the dialog will not run.

Hope this helps!

Comment: When i call w.set("myDialog",d) in AddButtonEntryPoint.js file and in Form.js file, I have written a code for cancel button and inside that , have written onClick function to hide the dialog which we have set but, when i click on Cancel then the dialog is not hiding and no operation is performing.